# loop splistitem in folder in powershell

Tags: powershell, splistitem, folder

I'm trying to loop all splistitem in a folder of a library.
I can get my library and have folder but i'm not able to get the items inside the folder.
When i display the listitem for folder, i've the number of folder at root library and inside folder not the splistitem in folder.
Here is what i did.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$url = "http://myspurl"
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $url
#retrieve list to update
$list = $SPWeb.Lists["myList"]
write-host $list.Title
#loop in lib
foreach($folder in $list.Folders)
{
if($folder.Name -eq "10002")
{
    #this count return me always the number of folder at the root of library and inside folder. and not the splistitem inside folder
    $folder.ListItems.Count
    foreach($item in $folder.ListItems)
    {
        #write-host "TEST"
        #$item = $file.Item
        #write-host "item = "$item.Title
        #$item.Url
    }

}
}
```

When i'll have splistitem inside folder i've to move it in an other folder depending of a meta

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The objects you get from $list.Folders are SPListItems not SPFolders so the ListItems property gives the Lists ListItemCollection not something for the folder.

To get the SPFolder you have to access $folder.Folder.

If what you're working with is a document library, then it's easy just access $folder.Folder.Files and you'll get the files in the SPFolder, then for each file you can get the Item

But if you're working with a list then you have to use a SPQuery to get the listitems in the folder like this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$url = "http://myspurl"
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $url
#retrieve list to update
$list = $SPWeb.Lists["myList"]
write-host $list.Title
#loop in lib
foreach($folder in $list.Folders)
{
  if($folder.Name -eq "10002")
  {
    $query = New-Object -Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery'
    $query.Folder = $folder.Folder
    $folderItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    foreach($item in $folderItems)
    {
      write-host $item.Title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @perJakobsen I am getting an error as 'Property 'Folder' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable' when I execute the below step _$query.Folder = $folder.Folder_  Could you please help me in rectifying this error?

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was barking up the Document Library Tree for a day until I read this and now I'm able to do what I need in a List Folder.